# Importing Picasso and OkHttp in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, picasso, okhttp

I need to expose some Picasso resources to satisfy a rather strange request. For this I need to import Picasso as a library project instead of a compiled jar. I've created a new Android Project and copied the contents of picasso\picasso\src\main\java (cloned master) to the src folder. Picasso uses OkHttp so I downloaded the latest release jar (2.3.0) and put it in the libs folder of the Picasso project; added it to the build path; selected the jar in the build path "Order and Export" preferences. Finally, I made the Picasso project a library and included it in the main project (also removed the old Picasso jar from libs).

The first time the application tries to make a Picasso request I get the following exception:

```
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache$4
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.<clinit>(DiskLruCache.java:810)
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:168)
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:77)
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:55)
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:45)
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$OkHttpLoaderCreator.create(Utils.java:424)
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.createDefaultDownloader(Utils.java:250)
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.build(Picasso.java:832)
04-12 17:04:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(5436):     at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:662)
```

The specified class seems to be in the jar but DiskLruCache.java seems broken into a total of 9 class files:

```
$ ls DiskLruCache*
DiskLruCache$1.class  DiskLruCache$4.class         DiskLruCache$Entry.class
DiskLruCache$2.class  DiskLruCache$Editor$1.class  DiskLruCache$Snapshot.class
DiskLruCache$3.class  DiskLruCache$Editor.class    DiskLruCache.class
```

I'm ready to provide additional info. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

The problem seems to be in the OkHttp jar. I've tried to import it in the main project along with the Picasso jar (latest - 2.5.2) and I get the same exception. I do not see any OkHttp warnings, indicating incompatibility as stated in some other threads.

Comment: same exception to me, with only the jar in libs folder.

Comment: Can you provide additional info about your case?

Comment: Using Eclipse Luna, with picasso-2.5.2 jar and okhttp-2.3.0 jar (i need it to use OkHttpClient) in my project's libs folder: I get the same identical error as yours.

Comment: Turns out you need Okio if you want to use OkHttp. Check the current answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OkHttp requires [Okio](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.squareup.okio%22%20AND%20a%3A%22okio%22) to work. This is mentioned on the [GitHub page](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), right under the download button. Importing the Okio jar fixed the NoClassDefFoundError. Here's a working configuration that I just tested:
[picasso:2.5.2](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.picasso%7Cpicasso%7C2.5.2%7Cjar); [okhttp:2.3.0](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.okhttp%7Cokhttp%7C2.3.0%7Cjar); [okio:1.3.0](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.okio%7Cokio%7C1.3.0%7Cjar).